# Is there any abnormality in this modeling?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, database-design, ef-fluent-api

[image: Model Sample]

I am using a table to centralize the addresses. **Customers** and **Suppliers** have a reference to address.

A **Customer** has an **Address**, an **Address** may or may not be associated with a **Customer**.

A **Supplier** has an **Address**, an **Address** may or may not be associated with a **Supplier**.

To ensure that an address is not associated with more than one **Customer** or **Supplier**, I have a **unique index** on the **Customer** and **Supplier** tables on **AddressID** column.

I am suspicious that this relationship is abnormal, because I am not able to map it using Entity-Framework with FluentAPI.

**Edit:**

- In my real scenario, the address table will have many more columns.
  In fact this is an adaptation to simplify a complex scenario where
  the address table is a financial release and the tables customer and
  supplier are representing the origin of the financial release, like
  Sale and Purchase.

Comment: Your unique indexes do not prevent a supplier and customer pointing to the same address, also what's the point of an address that is not associated with anybody? If you're not going to share the addresses between multiple customers/suppliers, I'd personally just get rid of it and have the fields in the customer/supplier tables. You could use an EF complex type to still have an object for them in your code.

Comment: Hi @MattiVirkkunen, I've edited my question to give more information on the real scenario.

Comment: I'd suggest to think of model in general. So your customer or supplier can not have different addresses? Usually they can and do actually have.

Comment: Have you considered a polymorphic relationship? In the Address table you will have two fields: addressee_type and addressee_id which will borrow from one of the two relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model seems reasonable.  The merits of having a second table when you want to enforce a 1-1 relationship may not be obvious to everyone.

I can think of two good reasons off-hand:

- You want the addresses in one place so you can treat all addresses equivalently (say geo-coding them, standardizing them, extracting features).
- The address column is long and many queries do not require it, so you gain efficiency by not storing the address with the rest of the data ("vertical partitioning").

And there may be other reasons.  I can't speak to why EF makes such relationships difficult to express.

Answer (score 1):

In your current design this is not EF issue and by it self it cannot prevent you to assign the same address to a customer and to a supplier. If you go this path you are the sole responsible of enforce this uniqueness through business rules and validations in your model.

In the other hand,  the correctness (or not) of your model  design, apart from what Linoff points out in his answer, depends of the nature of your problem and what important and address is to your business. For example, if this is an app for Post Office, then the Address merits an individual table, as it will be one of the core concepts to your application. But if not, with the current approach you are going to add complexity to your model.